# rails CanCan - Defining a permission for a nested model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

I have two models:

```
Thread (id, title)
ThreadParticipation (id, thread_id, user_id)
```

I want to define something like:

```
can :create, ThreadParticipation if the user is a ThreadParticipation
```

example:

```
for
    thread: (1, 'hello world')
    thread_participation: (313, 1, 13) -- where 13 is the user_id
```

I tried:

```
can :create, ThreadParticipation, :thread_participations => { :user_id => current_user.id }
```

But that errors. Any ideas?

Comment: Was it a very very very very very severe error ? :D It's hard to diagnose without some error message!

Answer (score 1):

`Thread` in general is just a bad model name, because it will clash with the `Thread` class defined in Ruby. I implemented this just recently. In my example, I have forums and topics. A person shouldn't be able to create a new topic in a forum they don't have read access to.

I defined a custom permission on the Forum object called `create_topic` for this:

```
can :create_topic, Forem::Forum do |forum|
  can?(:read, forum) && user.can_create_forem_topics?(forum)
end
```

Where `can_create_forem_topics?` is just defined on the `User` model like this:

```
def can_create_forem_topics?(forum)
  # code goes here
end
```

Then I just use this custom `:create_topic` ability in the `new` and `create` actions in my `TopicsController`, where `@forum` is defined by a `before_filter`:

```
authorize! :create_topic, @forum
```

And if I need to use it in views:

```
can? :create_topic, @forum
```

by defining a custom permission on the parent object,

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently trying to achieve something similiar, but I don't have the whole sight into this. Try this:

```
can :create, ThreadParticipation => Thread, do |participation, thread|
  # your definition here
end
```

This should also work without a block.

EDIT: drop the part above, that doesn't work yet in CanCan. I implemented my own solution, but it requires you to authorize controller actions manually, which is not as beautify, but more secure in my opinion.

I implemented it this way for my project:
https://gist.github.com/822208

Comment: Thanks but I'm confused. This is CanCan supported or not? I'm really looking for a CanCan solution w/o adding more complexity...

Comment: CanCan doesn't support nested resources at the moment (IMO). The gist solution IS a CanCan solution, look at it again. I just don't use can? ... in my views but user_ability.can? because with can? you can only take one argument (current_user or whatever). wehn creating an ability by yourself, you can define more (like in my example, user and company) and can work on this.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would user

```
user
```

not 
    current_user

within ability.rb. Is this your error? As well your ability is specified incorrectly. You want

```
can :create, ThreadParticipation, :user_id => user.id
```

Note that **:user_id** is a property of ThreadParticipation model